# What is the best way to print one answer?

Tags: support, export

Suppose I want to print one answer (out of many). Is there an option to achieve that without printing parts of adjacent answers?

Comment: Also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/how-to-use-math-stackprinter

Comment: @AsafKaragila Am I correct: That one can prepare the the entire file to be printed, the question and all the answers as one document, and then restrict printer to a segment. Each answer is not a separate file.

Comment: I'm... not sure? You can try and set it to print to a .pdf file and look at the result yourself.

Comment: Meta.SO: [Can I print a single answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128703/can-i-print-a-single-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a very naive solution. I used [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) to prepare [a question together with answers](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=633582&service=math.stackexchange).

I saved the page generated by StackPrinter. I obtained a html-file which looked like [this](http://pastebin.com/SaR3PZjy).

Then I simply edited it manually. I have removed almost all parts outside of `<div class="answers"> ... </div>`. (I left the question title, but if you want, you can remove it too.) In the part I left, I kept the part between `<div class="answer-details"> ... </div>` and `<div class="answer"> ... </div>` for the specific answer that I wanted. (If there are several answers, there are more such blocks.) The resulting file looked like [this](http://pastebin.com/Mr6shxvT). You can have a look [here](http://jsbin.com/oNaxoro/1) how it is rendered.

This is rather cumbersome, but if you do not need this often, it is doable.

---

You should definitely have a look at suggestions in meta.SO post [Can I print a single answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128703/can-i-print-a-single-answer). If you are familiar with userscripts, you can try the script which is provided in one of the answers there.